# Salvar no banco de Dados as informações de uma variável no Codeigniter

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, variáveis, controller

Eu estou recebendo da API do Cosmos diversas informações de um produto e armazenando elas em variáveis, porém como faço para salvar as informações dessas varáveis no Banco de Dados?

**VIEW**

```
 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 $data = curl_exec($curl);

 if ($data === false || $data == NULL) {
     var_dump(curl_error($curl));
 } else {
     $array = json_decode($data);
     $linkimg = $array->thumbnail;
     $nomeprdt = $array->description;
     $segmentacao = $array->ncm->description;
```

Eu queria passar para o Banco de dados o $nomeprdt e $segmentacao.

**MODEL**

```
    public function uploadtest($id,$nomeprdt,$segmentacao)
    {
      if($id > 0){
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO produto(nomeprdt, segprdt) VALUES(? , ?)",$nomeprdt,$segmentacao);
      }else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function upload_dcr(){
  $this->Produto_model->uploadtest($id,$nomeprdt,$segmentacao);
}
```

Comment: Já tentaste usar [dados do tipo JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) na criação da tabela `produto`? Ou em alternativa, porque não utilizar `serialize` do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php).

Comment: Qual o erro que é apresentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que o conteúdo da `view` está equivocado. No seu caso, a `view` primeiro deveria servir para dizer ao usuário *"Me dê uma URL para eu consultar!"* e depois "*Produto inserido com sucesso!"*, *"Produto já existe no cadastro!"*, *"Erro tal!"* etc.

Toda a implementação com o cURL deveria estar no `controller`.

Um primeiro método no controller serveria apenas para chamar uma `view` que contém um `form` de método `post` pedindo ao usuário para informar uma URL com `<input type="url" name="url" required autofocus>`.

Depois um outro método recebe esta URL, valida esta URL, processa as operações com o cURL, obtém o JSON, chama o `model` (sem o parâmetro $id se é autoincremento) e, baseado no `$this->db->affected_rows()` descobre-se se conseguiu ou não inserir o produto. De modo bem grosseiro é possível dar um echo do `affected_rows()` sem ter `view` para este processamento. É possível ainda juntar os métodos no controller num só, se preferir, tendo por base se está ou não recebendo a variável URL por `post`.

Considerações sobre as implementações dadas no seu exemplo:

- Não está claro, para não dizer incorreto, de onde vem a variável `$url`.
- No método `uploadtest()` é preciso remover o parâmetro desnecessário $id. Se este não for autoincremento, você terá que calculá-lo antes de inserir o produto, dentro do próprio método `uploadtest()`, então não faz sentido informá-lo nunca.
- No método `uploadtest()` falta transformar os parâmetros para query em array:

  ```
  $this->db->query("INSERT INTO produto(nomeprdt, segprdt) SELECT ?, ?", array($nomeprdt, $segmentacao));
  ```

E no método `uploadtest()` é bom dar um retorno útil, qual se pode exibir na tela para você entender o que está acontecendo:

```
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Dê um echo da chamada do modelo para ver quantas linhas foram inseridas:

```
    echo($this->Produto_model->uploadtest($nomeprdt,$segmentacao));
```